# How to send a POST parameter that will arrive in PHP as an associative array?

Tags: php, http, http-post

I want to send data to PHP API that reads data like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$name = $data['name'];
$foo = $data['sub']['foo'];
```

to send the ID, the query would look like id=123

but I'm not sure how the data parameter should be encoded - is it simply URL encoding of `id=123&data['name']=name` -> `id=123&data%5B%27name%27%5D=name` and similarly for the deeper nested array?

(I'm doing the request from Android, but I'm interested in the body of the POST request)

Comment: I'm referring to this feature: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#87650

Comment: Are you trying to send `$_POST` data via url?

Comment: @MarkM of course not, I'm just writing the post body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do that by making sure the parameter are being encoded properly

For example if you encode the following

```
ser[name]=Bob Smith&user[age]=47&user[sex]=M&
user[dob]=5/12/1956&pastimes[0]=golf&pastimes[1]=opera&
pastimes[2]=poker&pastimes[3]=rap&children[bobby][age]=12&
children[bobby][sex]=M&children[sally][age]=8&
children[sally][sex]=F&flags_0=CEO
```

Go to this site and paste either your code or the code that I provided
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ then click encode

and pass it to your URL as parameters.

If you need to generate those via PHP, maybe you should take a look at this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: so the trick might be in not using quotes in the indexes for the array - `children[bobby][age] vs children['bobby']['age']`?

Comment: Exactly. even if you need a key that has white space, you can do something like ser[my name]=Bob Smith which will result in ser%5Bmy%20name%5D%3DBob%20Smith

Comment: yes, that's it, even the comment at PHP documentation was right, I must have misread it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSON. You send JSON from your app and do a simple json_decode in the Server.

Comment: I cannot change the API, it's made by a third party, so I have to accomodate

Answer (score 0):

In your case where you have to follow an API use this format:

data[name]=User&data[sub][foo]=Hithere

Source:
http://homakov.blogspot.de/2012/06/x-www-form-urlencoded-vs-json-pros-and.html?m=1